# How to offset the title control in Titanium

Tags: ios, controls, titanium, title, offset

How do I offset the title control in titanium?

Right now I am trying to put a left: -100 property on the label that is in the title control and that works for when you open up the view but then it moves back into the center.

Are there any suggestions on how I can achieve this move over?

Thanks in advance!

```
var txtSearch = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    hintText: 'Keyword to search for',
    height: 'auto',
    width: 220,
    left: -100,
    font: {fontSize: 12},
    enabled: true,
    keyboardType:Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_EMAIL,  
    returnKeyType:Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_DEFAULT,  
    borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
    autocapitalization: Titanium.UI.TEXT_AUTOCAPITALIZATION_NONE,
    clearButtonMode: Titanium.UI.INPUT_BUTTONMODE_ONFOCUS
});
win.setTitleControl(txtSearch);

var btnSearch = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: 'Search',
    height: 'auto',
    width: 'auto',
    font: {fontSize: 13}
});
win.rightNavButton = btnSearch;
```

If I click the search button and it brings me to the search results page and then I hit the back button the textbox is not moved over and looks fine.. Only when the page first loads

Comment: editited @JosiahHester

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the text field to a view, then setting the view as the title control:

```
var container = Ti.UI.createView({
    width: 320
});

var txtSearch = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    hintText: 'Keyword to search for',
    height: 'auto',
    width: 220,
    left: 0,
    font: {fontSize: 12},
    enabled: true,
    keyboardType:Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_EMAIL,  
    returnKeyType:Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_DEFAULT,  
    borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
    autocapitalization: Titanium.UI.TEXT_AUTOCAPITALIZATION_NONE,
    clearButtonMode: Titanium.UI.INPUT_BUTTONMODE_ONFOCUS
});
container.add(txtSearch);
win.setTitleControl(container);
```